# Find what tags will be downloaded with `docker pull ubuntu`

Tags: docker

When I run in docker 1.2 `docker pull ubuntu` a lot of tags are downloaded. (In the version 1.3 this was changed — to download all the tags I need to run `docker pull ubuntu --all-tags`

I know that I can see the tags what are going to be downloaded on the Docker Hub — https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/tags/manage/

Is there a way to find out the list of tags that are to be downloaded from docker console utilities?

Answer (score 0):

Docker pull without an explicit tag will pull the "latest" tag. If you call pull with "--all-tags" flag it should then pull all the tags for that image.

Documentation for docker pull is here:

https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#pull

Comment: This is the behaviour starting from docker 1.3. In docker 1.2 `docker pull ubuntu` downloads all the tags — http://docs.docker.com/v1.2/reference/commandline/cli/#pull